# Gitlab CI/CD trouble with docker version

Tags: docker, gitlab

Can someone help me to fix this problem  with gitlab CI/CD

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: client is newer than server 
(client API version: 1.25, server API version: 1.24) (docker.go:1039:0s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using docker-ce on centos8, in this case:

```
# yum search docker-ce
docker-ce.x86_64 : The open-source application container engine
docker-ce-cli.x86_64 : The open-source application container engine

# yum update docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

Or install specific compatible versions:

```
# yum install docker-ce-19.03.9 docker-ce-cli-19.03.7
```

Edit:
Also do not forget to update gitlab-runner

Comment: Do I need to configure it in gitlab ci config file?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing you can do via gitlab-ci.yml you have to update docker and gitlab-runner

Answer (score 0):

Are your using dind? If yes, just use an older version like

```
  services:
    - docker:18.09-dind
```

if you are using the latest tag, you will face this error every time the docker team updates the dind image